# Make sure that the controller has a parameterless public constructor in Unity

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, dependency-injection, unity-container

I got this problem with the Controller:
An error occurred when trying to create a controller of type '***.WebMvc.Controllers.HomeController'. Make sure that the controller has a parameterless public constructor.

Find the solution for the ApiController, but didn't find anything about normal Controller.

Created new MVC 4 project from scratch.

HomeController.cs:

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    private IAccountingUow _uow;
    public HomeController(IAccountingUow uow)
    {
        _uow = uow;
    }
```

UnityDependencyResoler.cs:

```
public class UnityDependencyResolver : IDependencyResolver
{
    private IUnityContainer _container;
    public UnityDependencyResolver(IUnityContainer container)
    {
        _container = container;
        RegisterTypes();
    }
    public object GetService(Type serviceType)
    {
        try
        {
            return _container.Resolve(serviceType);
        }catch
        {
            return null;
        }
    }

    public IEnumerable<object> GetServices(Type serviceType)
    {
        try
        {
            return _container.ResolveAll(serviceType);
        }catch
        {
            return null;
        }
    }

    private void RegisterTypes()
    {
        _container.RegisterType<IAccountingUow, AccountingUow>();

    }
}
```

Global.asax

```
    protected void Application_Start()
    {
        //Omitted
        DependencyResolver.SetResolver( new UnityDependencyResolver( new UnityContainer()));

    }
```

Debugged and found out, that there are even no attempts to resolve IAccountingUow.

What i'm doing wrong?
Thinking about it whole day.

Comment: please post the whole exception's stacktrace

Comment: My issue resolved following [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34991456/2315972)

Answer (score 6):

Found where is the issue. Maybe some one will face the same.
The problem is that Unity could not resolve the `IAccountingUow`, because of hierarchical dependancy on interfaces.

`AccountingUow` class has two contuctors

```
    public AccountingUow( IRepositoryProvider repositoryProvider)
    {
        Init(repositoryProvider);
    }
    public AccountingUow()
    {
        Init( new RepositoryProvider(new RepositoryFactories()) );
    }
```

Dependency Resolver is not smart enought to take the default parametless contructor. It tries to take interface dependant contructor and fails to resolve it, cause there are no rules for resolving it.

I commented out interface dependant constructor and everything worked fine.

I will post later resolver for the first contructor, maybe someone will use it.

Comment: hi Yaroslav, I got the same problem, but it's related to IUserStore which is in IdentityConfig.cs and I cannot find the AccountingUow in my MVC 5 project, could you please post your update? thanks

Answer (score 3):

This can also be due to an exception in the parameter-injected constructor of the outer type that is being resolved. The dependencies of that type's constructor might be getting resolved successfully, but if there is an exception in the outer constructor, Unity will report it as "`Type` `Test.Controllers.MyControllerWithInjectedDependencies` does not have a default constructor".

Answer (score 0):

Install Nuget Package Unit.WebAP instead of Unity.MVC5 Make sure the correct unity package is installed using nuget

I Installed Unity.MVC5 and was facing similar exception "parameterless constructor"